# How to have a fixed width/height image always centered in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a way to have an image dynamically centered on any div size. How is this possible?

I have posted a jsFiddle for better understanding here http://jsfiddle.net/4exmm/ but as I said the div size is changed using a PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertically and horizontally aligned:

http://jsfiddle.net/4exmm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Make your div `text-align: center`. http://jsfiddle.net/4exmm/1/

```
#image {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this rule to `#image`:

```
text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `text-align: center` on the `div`

you could also make your img `margin: 0 auto` to keep it aligned withing whatever object